# Convert blob into URL in ReactNative

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, axios, blob

I have issue in downloading a file into my ReactNative app

the backend response

`{"_data": {"__collector": {}, "blobId": "E582A159-8E6E-48D2-B245-CA62A7005706", "name": "v1-download-proforma-invoice.json", "offset": 0, "size": 108769, "type": "application/json"}}`

I need to download the blob file to the device

Looks I need a data URL to to download the file into my device

How to generate that URL from that response in ReactNative?

I use useMutation hook in react-query with Axios to handle that operation

Comment: I would say that you miss the actual data, you don't have any blob here only some identifier. So I would say you can't download that thing if this is all you have.

Comment: @jcubic I see you're right, is there any certain configs I should assign to axios request, so it can return the actual blob data for me?

Comment: No, you can't. The issue is on the server that needs to return proper data. If you work with 3rd party data read the documentation, if it's your API then you need to modify the backend code. If you have a problem with that ask a question about the backend you have.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i got raw data inside : "response.request._response".

```
  await RNFS.writeFile(
    sourceFilePath,
    response.request._response,
    "base64"
  );
```

Answer (score -1):

To download the data you can use `useQuery`, and provide the prop `onSuccess`:

```
onSuccess:(blobData)=>{
   const dataUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blobData);
   //Now that you have the URL you can download your file.
   //or open it in a browser based on your needs
}
```